# Espera el programa un expresión cuando espera de el un construción

Tags: c++

Quiero construir **min-heap** con C++ pero tengo un problema, pienso que proviene del constructor o del fichero `.h`. Cuando traigo compilar con `$ g++ main.cpp -o main`

Me dice el compilador que

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: main.cpp:13:6: error: expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token Heap(int size);
>
> main.cpp:13:7: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’ Heap(int size);

Aquí está el fichero heap.cpp

```
// array version
#include "heap.h"

using namespace std;

Heap::Heap(int size):array[size]
{
    build_minheap(size);
}
void Heap::build_minheap(int size)
{/*cosas que no estan importantes*/}
void Heap::min_heapify(int i)
{/*cosas que no estan importantes*/}
```

Aquí está el fichero heap.h :

```
#ifndef HEAP_H_INCLUDED
#define HEAP_H_INCLUDED

class Heap
{
    public:
    Heap(int size);
    void heapify(int i);
    void build_minheap();

    private:
    int array[];    

};


#endif // MATH_H_INCLUDED
```

Y aquí está el main.cpp :

```
#include<heap.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int size,i,x;
    cout<<"enter no of elements of array\n";
    cin>>size;
    Heap(int size);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int variable = 5;
int array[variable];
```

La segunda línea del código se corresponde con una VLA (**V**ariable **L**ength **A**rray) y es una característica no permitida en el estándar de C++ (hay algunos compiladores y algunas extensiones que lo soportan pero al no estar en el estándar es mejor evitarlo)

Por otro lado, el compilador necesita conocer, en tiempo de compilación, el tamaño del objeto para poder realizar las reservas de memoria oportunas. Esto quiere decir que el tamaño de `array` debe estar determinado en la interfaz de la clase:

```
class Heap
{
  int array[/*falta tamaño aqui*/];    
};
```

La solución pasa por usar memoria dinámica. Los punteros ocupan un tamaño fijo (es la memoria referenciada la que tiene un tamaño variable) y ello permite que el compilador pueda completar su tarea:

```
class Heap
{
  public:
    Heap(int size);
    ~Heap(); // Ahora el destructor es necesario

  private:
    int* array;    
};

Heap::Heap(int size)
  : array(new int[size])
{ }

Heap::~Heap()
{ delete[] array; }
```

El uso de la variable es exactamente el mismo que el que pretendías inicialmente.

Ahora bien, para evitar escribir más allá del espacio reservado necesitas almacenar también el tamaño de la reserva, ya que a partir de un puntero es imposible saber cual es el tamaño de la reserva de memoria:

```
class Heap
{
  public:
    Heap(int size);
    ~Heap(); // Ahora el destructor es necesario

  private:
    int size;
    int* array;    
};

Heap::Heap(int size)
  : size(size),
    array(new int[size])
{ }
```

Así puedes usar la variable miembro `size` para verificar que no se intenta acceder a un valor fuera de los límites previstos.

Otro error que tienes se encuentra en esta línea:

```
int main()
{
  // ...
  Heap(int size); // <<--- AQUI
}
```

Ahí estás declarando una función y tu lo que pretendes es crear un objeto de tipo `Heap`, que sería así:

```
int main()
{
  // ...

  // opcion 1
  Heap heap(size);

  // opcion 2
  Heap heap = Heap(size);

  // opcion 3 (memoria dinamica - requiere delete)
  Heap* heap = new Heap(size); 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias para esta respuesta. He leido, aprendido y modificado mi codigo. Sin embargo hoy tengo un error `undefined reference to Heap::(int)` en `main.cpp`. He actualizado mi codigo para añadir `#include<heap.h>` en el texto `main.cpp` puesto aquí pero no funciona sin embargo. Mi constructor esta en una clase distincta de las declaraciones : tengo `heap.cpp` con el constructor 

Heap::Heap(int size):array[size]
{
    build_minheap(size);
}

y `heap.h` con las declraciones a diferencia de usted.

Comment: @Marine1 ¿Y qué tiene la línea que te da error?

Comment: Hizo $ `g++ main.cpp -o main` y me da :
`In function main:
main.cpp(.text+0x50): undefined reference to Heap::Heap(int)'` y `collect2:error: ld returned 1 exit status` Entonces esta el programa en lugar de una linea ...

Comment: @Marine1 Si la implementación de `Heap` está en, por ejemplo, `heap.cpp` tendrás que crear el correspondiente `heap.o` e incluirlo en el link para generar el ejecutable. El error te está diciendo que el compilador no encuentra la implementación del constructor de `Heap`

Comment: Entendido, voy a hacer `g++ heap.cpp -o heap` primero !

Comment: @Marine1 Más bien tendrías que hacer `g++ main.cpp heap.cpp -o main`. Lo que el compilador va a intentar con la instrucción que has puesto es crear un ejecutable a partir de `heap.cpp` y no eso no es correcto

Answer (score 1):

```
Heap(int size);
```

1. Solo declaras el tipo de la variable cuando la defines; al usarla únicamente escribes el nombre.
2. En C++, a diferencia de Java, los objetos pueden ser referencias (punteros a objetos, creados con `new`), o definidos directamente como variables locales. Si defines una variable local, deberías darle el nombre; si defines una referencia, usar `new`.

En resumen, o bien

```
Heap miHeap(size);
```

o

```
new Heap(size);
```

La segunda forma, por supuesto, tiene el problema de que no guardas el puntero en ninguna variable por lo cual no puedes acceder (ni liberar) el objeto posteriormente --> *memory leak*